# Insert a field value from another table dynamically

Tags: mysql

It's  a newbie question on mysql, I have the following two tables in same database

```
       Users                                    vehicles

User   Level   Group                Vehicle    User    GroupID
 A       0       AG                   x         A         x
 a1      1       AG                   y         a2        x  
 a2      1       AG                   z         a1        x
 B       0       BG                   
 b1      1       BG
 b2      1       BG
```

User.user having Level = 0 is a superUser(Only one superUSer per Group).

In vehicles User is a Fk on Users.user, now needed to create a new column GroupID. Here i got into the problem, i need to set the **GroupID** value to Users.User who is superUser of Vehicles.User.

Finally the Vehicles table should look like

```
  Vehicle    User    GroupID
    x         A         A
    y         a2        A  
    z         a1        A
```

Any sample query to do this for the entire Vehicles table will be helpful for me, Thanks.

Comment: where is your User Group table ?

Comment: User Group is a column in Users table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the table like this, for the new column.

```
UPDATE
    vehicles v
SET
    v.GroupID = (SELECT User FROM Users WHERE Level = 0 AND Group IN (SELECT Group FROM Users WHERE User = v.User));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the user defined variables to to fill up your vehicles table according to their relevant group

```
UPDATE `vehicles` v
JOIN (
SELECT 
`User` ,
@g:=`Level`,
@u:= CASE WHEN @g= 0 THEN `User` ELSE @u END `new_group`
FROM users 
JOIN(SELECT @g:=-1 ,@u:='') t
ORDER BY `User` ,`Level`
) n
ON(n.`User` = v.`User`)
SET v.GroupID = n.new_group
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    UPDATE
        user.vehicles
    SET
        user.vehicles.GroupID = user.user.User
    FROM
        user.vehicles
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT User FROM user.user WHERE Level = 0) user.user

     ON
    user.user.User = user.vehicles.User
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE
    user.vehicles
SET
    user.vehicles.GroupID = (SELECT User FROM (SELECT User FROM user.user WHERE Level = 0))
```

Try Above Query I Hope Help You........!!